# Ошибка "ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError)" при работе с mySQL

Tags: python, flask, python-2.x, openshift, flask-sqlalchemy

Задача состоит в получении данных с таблицы Страны с mysql на OpenShift.

Для обращения к mysql используется Flask, но выдается ошибка.

**Исходный скрипт:**

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect, \
 render_template, abort, send_from_directory, g
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('flaskapp.cfg')
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME')
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST')
app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT')
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME')
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL') + os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.create_all()

class Countries(db.Model):
    IdCountry = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Country = db.Column(db.String(100))

def __init__(self, country):
    self.Country = country

def __repr__(self):
    return '<Country %r>' % self.Country

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/<path:resource>')
def serveStaticResource(resource):
    return send_from_directory('static/', resource)

@app.route("/test")
def test():
    return "<strong>Value</strong>"

@app.route("/name")
def name():
    a = Countries.query.all()
    return "Name" + str(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**Log из облака**

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'mobiledentist.countries' doesn't exist") 'SELECT countries.`IdCountry` AS `countries_IdCountry`, countries.`Country` AS `countries_Country` \nFROM countries' ()
```

Comment: А попробуйте `db.create_all()` перенести нижу, скажем перед `app.run()` после `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: Вывел ошибку
    IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: У вас с табуляцией проблемы. Уберите её и ошибка исчезнет.

Comment: а можно немного конкретнее, ибо я новичок в python

Comment: Вы где пишите код?

Comment: Вообщем суть задачи в том, что надо убрать табы на пробелы.